# How can I get program out from eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, stdout

I write an eclipse plugin and I want to use the program stdout which is running as an application or which is debugged. 
For example: IF I create a simple java "Hello World" project with this statement: `System.out.println("Hello World!")` And if I run this in eclipse and, as soon as the program execute this sentence I want to get an event in the plugin that the program write the stdout *"Hello World!"*

Thanks

Benedek

Comment: What's wrong with just using the Eclipse Console? It even has a setting to *Show Console When Standard Out Changes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers` extension point to define a console line tracker class. The class must implement `IConsoleLineTracker` (or `IConsoleLineTrackerExtension`).

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers">
  <consoleLineTracker 
     id="com.example.ExampleConsoleLineTracker"
     class="com.example.ExampleConsoleLineTracker"
     processType="java">
  </consoleLineTracker>
</extension>
```

You may have to change the `processType` depending on what you want to track.

More details in the [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_debug_ui_consoleLineTrackers.html)